# Is it possible to calculate the standard deviation from the mean and geometric standard deviation of the distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, standard-deviation

I need to calculate the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of a [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) from which I only know the mean value and the [geometric standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_standard_deviation).

Is there a function or algorithm that converts from one standard deviation to the other?

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article, the mean and GSD are $\exp(\mu+\frac12\sigma^2)$ and $\exp\sigma$ respectively, so you should be able to solve for the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$. Then the standard deviation is $\exp(\mu+\frac12\sigma^2)\sqrt{\exp\sigma^2-1}$.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for your comment! In the article about geometric standard deviation there is also the relationship $\sigma_\mathrm{g} = \mathrm{exp}(\sigma(\mathrm{ln}(A)))$. Is that in accordance with your relations?